# Haskell Prelude.read: no parse String

Tags: haskell

from haskell examples http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses

```
ghci> read "5" :: Int  
5  
ghci> read "5" :: Float  
5.0  
ghci> (read "5" :: Float) * 4  
20.0  
ghci> read "[1,2,3,4]" :: [Int]  
[1,2,3,4]  
ghci> read "(3, 'a')" :: (Int, Char)  
(3, 'a')
```

but when I try

```
read "asdf" :: String
```

or

```
read "asdf" :: [Char]
```

I get exception

> Prelude.read No Parse

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is because the string representation you have is not the string representation of a `String`, it needs quotes embedded in the string itself:

```
> read "\"asdf\"" :: String
"asdf"
```

This is so that `read . show === id` for `String`:

```
> show "asdf"
"\"asdf\""
> read $ show "asdf" :: String
"asdf"
```

As a side note, it's always a good idea to instead use the `readMaybe` function from `Text.Read`:

```
> :t readMaybe
readMaybe :: Read a => String -> Maybe a
> readMaybe "asdf" :: Maybe String
Nothing
> readMaybe "\"asdf\"" :: Maybe String
Just "asdf"
```

This avoids the (in my opinion) broken `read` function which raises an exception on parse failure.