# Haskell recursive function that returns number strings, Prelude.read: no parse

Tags: string, haskell, recursion, numbers

I'm new at Haskell programming and I'm trying to make a recursive function "pyramid" that returns string like this:

pyramid 0 ==> "0"

pyramid 1 ==> "0,1,0"

pyramid 2 ==> "0,1,2,1,0"

pyramid 3 ==> "0,1,2,3,2,1,0"

--**update**--

```
pyramidHelper :: Integer -> String
pyramidHelper n | n == 0 = ['0']
                | otherwise = pyramidHelper (n-1) ++ [','] ++ ['n'] ++ [','] ++ pyramidHelper (n-1)


pyramid :: Integer -> String
pyramid n   | n == 0    = show 0
            | otherwise = pyramidHelper n
```

I'm getting *Exception: 'Prelude.read: no parse'*. I read [Haskell Prelude.read: no parse String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947925/haskell-prelude-read-no-parse-string) and tried to change the code, but wasn't successful.

Comment: I find it rather weird to use strings instead of lists of integers in the first place. By using strings you basically "lose information".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem This is an exercise and I'm learning lists later, so that's why I have to use strings. :)

Comment: Strings *are* lists, which is why you can use `(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]` on them. `"0,1,0"` is just syntactic sugar for `['0', ',', '1', ',', '0']`.

Comment: @chepner Okay, thanks that helps a lot! :)

Comment: You aren't calling `read` anywhere, so it's hard to see how you could get an error message from it.

Answer (score 1):

this can get you started...

```
pyramidNumbers n = [0..n] ++ [(n-1),(n-2)..0]
```